# Why do I get an error in python saying that a method cannot be found even though I previously defined the method?

Tags: python

```
index = 0
def changeColor():
    global index
    if index%2==0:
        label.configure(bg = "purple")
    else:
        label.configure(bg = "blue")
    index+=1
    label.after(1000, changeColor)   

def Start (self): # command when start button is clicked in GUI
    self.root = Tk()
    self.root.geometry("500x300")
    mainContainer = Frame (self.root)
    label = Label(mainContainer, text = "")
    label.pack(side = LEFT, ipadx = 5, ipady = 5)
    mainContainer.pack()
    label.after(1000, changeColor)
    self.root.mainloop()
```

I get an error saying: NameError: global name 'changeColor' is not defined. Why does this occur and how would I fix it?

Comment: because you try to use variable changeColor in `label.after(1000, changeColor)`, before class is defined

Comment: so like the change i made? -- because that does not work

Comment: what has happened to this line? `    label.after(1000, changeColor)    index = 0`

Comment: try to convey a little bit more information about your source code.
is somewhat difficult to figure out your functions are object methods

Comment: this program is basically apart of a larger GUI; there is a start button that performs a certain command (basically changing colors) and the change color method is invoked within the start command to do this

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like the problem might be what's not in the snippet. Are both of these functions part of a class definition? From the use of self as an argument in Start, and label in changeColor, it looks like it might be.

If so, let's say it's class Foo, then changeColor is really Foo.changeColor. To use it, you'd pull it outside of the class, or pass it as self.changeColor from Start.

**EDIT:** Three other things you should do to clean up the style:

- Make changeColor take self as an argument, so it's a proper method of the class.
- Make label a member of the object; i.e. make it self.label, so changeColor can access it.
- Get rid of the global index. Instead, query the label's current color (`self.label['bg']`) to figure out what state it's in.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  index = 0
  def changeColor(self):
    global index
    if index%2==0:
      self.label.configure(bg = "purple")
    else:
        self.label.configure(bg = "blue")
    index+=1

def Start (self): # command when start button is clicked in GUI
    self.root = Tk()
    self.root.geometry("500x300")
    mainContainer = Frame (self.root)
    label = Label(mainContainer, text = "")
    label.pack(side = LEFT, ipadx = 5, ipady = 5)
    mainContainer.pack()
    label.after(1000, self.changeColor)
    # above should really be lambda: changeColor()
    self.root.mainloop()
```

working example

```
>>> def f(): print f
...
>>> def h(f): f()
...
>>> def g(): h(f)
...
>>> g()
<function f at 0x7f2262a8c8c0>
```

Comment: @sam look for mistakes elsewhere, for example `label` is undefined

Comment: hmm.. see when i delete the def Start (self) and leave all the code from self.root = Tk() to self.root.mainloop() after it by itself, then my program works
any ideas about this?

Comment: @sam are this functions inside class!?

Comment: @sam see corrections in my post, be aware you most likely will get other errors